# How does git read-tree work without -m or --reset option

Tags: git

I'm trying to figure out how `git read-tree` works when multiple trees are specified but no `-m` or `--reset` option is present. The man page only describes the behaviour for multiple trees when merging. There's a test case https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/t/t1008-read-tree-overlay.sh as part of the test suite which tests "multi-tree read-tree without merging". The test case sets up three trees which look like the following:

initial:

`100644 blob 5626abf0f72e58d7a153368ba57db4c673c0e171    a`

master:

`100644 blob 5626abf0f72e58d7a153368ba57db4c673c0e171    a
100644 blob f719efd430d52bcfc8566a43b2eb655688d38871    b`

side:

`100644 blob 5626abf0f72e58d7a153368ba57db4c673c0e171    a
100644 blob 8510665149157c2bc901848c3e0b746954e9cbd9    b/c`

I would expect a 3-way read-tree of `initial`, `master`, and `side` to result in a stage 0 file `a`, a stage 2 `b`, and a stage 3 `b/c` because of the conflict between `b` and `b/c` (which is, in fact, the result when you run `read-tree -m initial master side` or `read-tree --reset initial master side` on those trees), but when run with no options it results in a stage 0 `a`, a stage 0 `b/c` and no `b` at all. Why is there no conflict between `b` and `b/c` when the `-m` option is missing? How does `b/c` win over `b` (which is the case regardless of the order of the trees on the command line when run without `-m`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me what the *purpose* of such a read-tree is, but the reason you get no conflict is that this kind of read-tree does in fact combine the three trees without merging (so that everything is at stage zero), and it's impossible to have a file and a directory that have the same name, so the directory entry overrides the file entry, removing `b` from the final index.

The underlying code (in [`unpack-trees.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c05048d43925ab8edcb36663752c2b4541911231/unpack-trees.c#L1283)) is used for `git diff-index` as well—see [this comment in `unpack_callback`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c05048d43925ab8edcb36663752c2b4541911231/unpack-trees.c#L1068)—and here it wants to know if it can skip a subtree.  Whether that has some effect on how the non-merge case is *intended* to behave, I'm not quite sure, but note that when we get to this bit of code, we have a dirmask and mask that do not match (since one tree has a directory and the other two have files).  [The `unpack_nondirectories` function](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c05048d43925ab8edcb36663752c2b4541911231/unpack-trees.c#L813) just sets `stage = 0` if `o->merge` is false, which is the case here.  (It seems like it might behave differently if the *last* tree has a directory in this position, as we'll set a conflict bit here, then `continue`.)